# How to get basename from each line in a file with Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with lines:

file1

```
./filled/Event_repeatFILLED.svelte
./dir2/Miscellaneous_servicesFILLED.svelte
./outline/Line_weightFILLED.svelte
./two-tone/ArchitectureFILLED.svelte
...many more lines ...
```

I'd like to create a file with only basenames:

file2

```
Event_repeatFILLED.svelte
Miscellaneous_servicesFILLED.svelte
Line_weightFILLED.svelte
ArchitectureFILLED.svelte
...
```

At the moment the following doesn't work.

```
sed 's/^.\///' file1 > file2
```

How can I do this using Shell/Bash?

Comment: You do realise that there is a command called `basename` which will do what you want?

Comment: @Bib, it won't automatically do that for a list of filenames in a file. If you have a solution to the question, post it as answer.

Comment: You _are already_ (almost) doing it with shell/`bash`. A large point of a shell is to glue other commands together to achieve an aim

Comment: Please also remember that "_the following doesn't work_" doesn't really tell us much. We know something's not working because you've posted here. Instead, consider answers to questions like these: What happened? What did you expect to happen? Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a different delimiter in the sed substitution command. For example:

```
$ sed 's|.*/||' file 
Event_repeatFILLED.svelte
Miscellaneous_servicesFILLED.svelte
Line_weightFILLED.svelte
ArchitectureFILLED.svelte
...many more lines ...
```

Alternatively:

```
$ perl -pe 's|.*/||' file 
Event_repeatFILLED.svelte
Miscellaneous_servicesFILLED.svelte
Line_weightFILLED.svelte
ArchitectureFILLED.svelte
...many more lines ...
```

Or, with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{print $NF}' file 
Event_repeatFILLED.svelte
Miscellaneous_servicesFILLED.svelte
Line_weightFILLED.svelte
ArchitectureFILLED.svelte
...many more lines ...
```

Or even something silly like:

```
$ rev file | cut -d / -f 1 | rev
Event_repeatFILLED.svelte
Miscellaneous_servicesFILLED.svelte
Line_weightFILLED.svelte
ArchitectureFILLED.svelte
...many more lines ...
```

Or you can use `basename` as suggested in the comments but that will be more complicated and slower:

```
$ while IFS= read -r fileName; do basename -- "$fileName"; done < file
Event_repeatFILLED.svelte
Miscellaneous_servicesFILLED.svelte
Line_weightFILLED.svelte
ArchitectureFILLED.svelte
```

Finally, if you really want a pure shell solution, you can do:

```
$ while IFS= read -r fileName; do printf '%s\n' "${fileName##*/}"; done < file
Event_repeatFILLED.svelte
Miscellaneous_servicesFILLED.svelte
Line_weightFILLED.svelte
ArchitectureFILLED.svelte
...many more lines ...
```

But don't use the two last ones, they are the least efficient and most complex. See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/22222).

Comment: Note that the `sed` one would return `$'St\xe9phane/file'` for an input like `$'Chazelas/St\xe9phane/file'` for instance if run in a UTF-8 locale for instance.

Comment: Note that most of those would return the empty string for `some/dir/` or `/`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes. I am assuming the OP wants file names, not directories and the input in the example seems to confirm that. But yes, both unicode weirdness and trailing slashes will confuse most of these approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Not to go too deeply into it, the immediate issue with your command is that the dot means "any *one* character" in regexes. You need `.*` to match an arbitrary number of characters (as many as possible in standard regexes).

So try

```
sed 's/^.*\///' file1 > file2
```

Caveats mentioned in other answers and comments apply.

Comment: @roaima, naah, I mostly just meant to point out the mistake that made their command not work. I wasn't planning on doing anything pretty here. Also the caveats mentioned in other answers and comments apply.

Answer (score 3):

With the GNU implementations of `xargs` and `basename`, you can do:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a file1 basename -a -- > file2
```

Using `basename` has the advantage of handling some special cases such as `/` or `/some/dir/` properly.

To do the equivalent by hand:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -e 's:^//*$:/:;t' -e 's:/*$::; s:.*/::' < file1 > file2
```

- `LC_ALL=C` needed as file paths are not guaranteed to be made of valid text in the locale
- `/` or `//`, `///`... treated specially first
- trailing `/`s removed
- and then stripping all up to the rightmost `/`.

If using `zsh`, you could also use its `:t` (for `t`ail) modifier (borrowed from `csh`):

```
print -rC1 -- ${${(f)"$(<file1)"}:t} > file2
```

Beware that for `/` (or `//`, `///`...) it differs from GNU `basename` in that it returns the empty string instead of `/`.

With `perl`:

```
perl -MFile::Basename -lpe '$_=basename$_' < file1 > file2
```